# why "X for X in DataFrame" is only giving the column names

Tags: python, pandas

```
y = [x for x in train]
```

Here, `train` is a dataframe of mnist data set.

I know this code is to convert everything in a list but it is only giving me the columns names(pixel1, pixel2...)  of the data frame.

Why it is not giving me my whole data as a list?

Comment: Because that is how a dataframe is defined - similar to a dict. Are you asking because you expected it to be different (i.e. consider it a bug), because you wanted it to work differently (i.e. need to know how) or are wondering why this design decision was made?

Comment: BTW, (not solving the problem) `[x for x in train]` does the same thing as `list(train)`

Answer (score 2):

That is how it is supposed to work. For example if you traverse a dictionary in the same way, you will only get the keys, not the values. In DataFrames, column names are like keys of dictionary.

Example with dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[3,4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9,0]}
>>> l = [x for x in d]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [d[x] for x in d]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 0]]
```

You need this:

```
y = [train[x].tolist() for x in train]
```

By the way, you can get the entire data as array with this:

```
y = train.values
```